# Do active model serializers change your db query or just format objects after AR makes the query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, serialization

Just learning about serializers and was wondering what's going on under the hood. Does it actually change your db query or do serializers just wrap around your model and then format the data nicely before passing it to your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, no change is made to any db query. Instead, the model handles querying the db for data and instantiating an object, then the serializer uses that instance and your serialization logic to format a response that the controller renders. Note that you can also [serialize POROs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/howto/serialize_poro.md).